# How do I solve a 'TypeError: "example"() takes no arguments' error?

Tags: python

I have created a simple MCQ based off a tutorial I have learnt on YouTube regarding classes and objects, and importing different python programs into one.

The following is what I have created:
 This is the class that I have created.

```
class MCQ:
    def __int__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

This is the second program titled MCQ_Code.

```
from MCQ_Code import MCQ
question_prompts = [
"What is the colour of a banana? \n(a) Red\n(b) Blue \n(c) Yellow\n(d) White\n\n",
"What is the colour of an apple? \n(a) Red\n(b) Blue \n(c) Yellow\n(d) White\n\n",
"What is the colour of blueberries? \n(a) Red\n(b) Blue \n(c) Yellow\n(d) White\n\n"
]

questions = [
MCQ(question_prompts[0], "c"),
MCQ(question_prompts[1], "a"),
MCQ(question_prompts[2], "b"),
]

def test(questions):
    score = 0
    for Qtion in questions:
        answer = input(Qtion.prompt)
        if answer == Qtion.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + "correct")
```

This is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Python/PyCharm/Projects/MCQ.py", line 10, in <module>
MCQ(question_prompts[0], "c"),
TypeError: MCQ() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Based on what I have learnt, I understand that this error is generated through the lack of incorrect/undefined parameters. However, I assigned the correct parameters in the classes while ensuring the objects of the class is correct. Apologies for my lack of understanding towards the topic and I will be very appreciative of all any help I can get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def __int__(self, prompt, answer):
```

You have a typo here; This should use `__init__` instead of `__int__`.

Note that `__int__` is a valid magic method, but it is used to convert your class to an `int` rather than to construct an instance of your class.

Answer (score 3):

the initialising function is called `__init__` not `__int__`